# Install multiple Pods in swift

Tags: swift, google-analytics, xcode6, cocoapods

I currently have the Google Places Pod in my Xcode workspace. I would also like to use Google analytics. 
Should I just add `pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'` to my Podfile and run `pod install` again the same as I did the first time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It will install any pods you have added.